# Add a sequence Generator column in sql view and execute filter condition based on sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

i have a sql view called  'test' which is  like ,

```
  Name  Profession
  Mak   Manager
  San   Doctor
```

I need to add a sequence column such that  it should looks like ,

```
  Srno   Name  Profession
    1     Mak   Manager
    2     San   Doctor
```

Now I need to query based on the sequence SrNo  like

```
    Select  * from  test where SrNo between 1 and  5.
```

But this  is not working

Comment: Do you know of [`IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)?

Comment: What happens when the data changes, and therefore the sequence number for a particular row also changes? Is that a problem?

Comment: Order is not inherent in tables.  So what order do you want the srNo to be applied in?  order by name, then profession, profession, then name "random" what?  raj kamuni's response would appear to work but order would be somewhat random.

Comment: how can  I apply  IDENTITY  in a sql view ?

Comment: Does it matter which 5 rows you get or is there some logic to what row gets what number?

Comment: Sean Lange 3 : N0 there is no special logic for what row gets what number. I just want to have a column that increments its value by 1 for each new record

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
With CTE1 AS(
SELECT row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as Sr_no,Name,Profession
from table_Name)
Select * From cte1 where Sr_No between 1 and  5.
```

Comment: This is the right answer (though it's a view named "test", not a table named "table_Name").